# PyCharm auto import NumPy as np

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

PyCharm has a neat option that allows when pressing `ctrl+enter` to automatically import libraries (e.g. os, sys, etc).

It used to work for NumPy as well, that is when writing:

```
z = np.zeros(5)
```

it would give a suggestions to `import numpy as np`.

However, after installing several packages this disappeared. Are these suggestions are defined anywhere? Can I change/add to them?

Comment: Several packages is quite ambiguous to decipher, also probably not worth it to fix this issue and just type `import numpy as np`